# Bootstrap button with hover animation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for solution for coding this design element.

http://prntscr.com/g3t4zm

My main problem is the first buttons design and the animation on hover.

How to make thin line around, how to make another circle around when hover?

Any idea?

Thanks.

Right now it looks like this:

```css
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}


/* style glyph */

.inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* add padding  */

.left-addon input {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.btn-round-lg {
  border: 5px solid;
  border-radius: 26px;
}

.btn-round-xs {
  border-radius: 26px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 5px solid;
}

.inp {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!--<div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-round-lg">Default</a></div>-->
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-round-lg">Success</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-round-lg">Info</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-round-lg">Warning</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-round-lg">Danger</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!--<div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round-xs">Default</a>-->
      <!--</div>-->
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-round-xs">Success</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-round-xs">Info</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-round-xs">Warning</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-round-xs">Danger</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a invisible border around the button and replace it with a blue border on `:hover`, and to make it smooth use `transition` like this:

```css
.button {
  padding: 4px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #00B1FF;
  color: white;
  border: 5px solid white;
  transition: border 0.2s ease;
}
.button:hover {
  border: 5px solid #81D9FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

And as for the other button,

```css
.button {
  padding: 4px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: blue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
  box-shadow : 0px 0px 0px 5px #00B1FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

Comment: Its working great thank you. Any idea how can I make this button?
http://prntscr.com/g3u0k7

Comment: @davodor Yea sure, I'll add that to my answer. Do you want it to have a hover effect?

Comment: Yes please. Thank you.

Comment: @davodor And what effect do you want?

Comment: I would like with this color: #00B1FF
Effect like the first

Answer (score 2):

To do the effect you are searching for, a way to do it is using *box-shadow* in CSS :

```css
.col-lg-2 {
  width : 150px;
  height : 50px;
  text-align : center;
  color : white;
  background-color : #aaaaaa;
  border-radius : 25px;
  transition : 0.3s;
}

.col-lg-2 a {
  color : white;
  font-family : Arial;
  font-size : 22px;
  text-align : center;
  text-transform : uppercase;
  text-decoration : none;
  line-height : 50px;
}

.col-lg-2:hover {
  transition : 0.3s;
  box-shadow : 0px 0px 1px 8px #aaaaaa;
  background-color : #828282;
  cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-round-lg">Info</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background: #00b1ff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  border: 6px solid #81d9ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  BUTTON
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One example here:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-round-lg">Warning</a>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-round-lg {
  background: #00b1ff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border:8px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 37px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  min-width: 186px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition:all 0.25s ease 0s;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family:arial;
}
.btn-round-lg:hover {
  border: 8px solid rgba(129, 217, 255, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Bootstrap.min.css file

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}


/* style glyph */

.inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* add padding  */

.left-addon input {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.btn-round-lg {
  border: 5px solid;
  border-radius: 26px;
}

.btn-round-xs {
  border-radius: 26px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 5px solid;
}

.inp {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  </style>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!--<div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-round-lg">Default</a></div>-->
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-round-lg">Success</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-round-lg">Info</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-round-lg">Warning</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-round-lg">Danger</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!--<div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round-xs">Default</a>-->
      <!--</div>-->
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-round-xs">Success</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-round-xs">Info</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-round-xs">Warning</a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-round-xs">Danger</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Would these help?

Animation with css :hover attribute.

Design of rounded corners with border-radius. I realize you already have them in your example, but you were asking about how to create this design in the original question...

```css
div{
  margin: 2em;
}

.mybutton{
  border: 3px solid blue; 
  margin: 3em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.mybutton:hover{
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="mybutton">Click me</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="mybutton">Click me</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="mybutton">Click me</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.btn {
border-radius: 25px !important;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 10px solid transparent !important;
}

.btn:hover {
border: 10px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-round-xl">Danger</a></div>
```